# Max Pool Size in web.config running on IIS Web Server

Tags: iis, web-config, max-pool-size

I have a cloud-based application where there can be up to 5000 "worker nodes" communicating with a web server. All 5000 could be started simultaneously and once online, would call an API method to pick-up a job. This API method in turn calls a SQL Server stored procedure to get the job details and return a response to the individual node. To prevent multiple nodes getting the same job, the stored procedure puts a lock on a particular database table while it executes.

Web Server is Windows 2016 Server running IIS 10.
SQL Server is Microsoft SQL Server Standard 2017

My question is how to best manage these connections through web.config or IIS settings. As far as I know, my main levers are

- Max Pool Size in web.config
- Connection time-out for IIS Site

I can increase the pool size to 10,000 of course and set the connection time-out to 2 or 3 minutes but I'm not sure if there's a best practice for managing something like this.

Comment: It is obviously that your API call is exclusive to each other due to the stored procedure and the lock, and calling it 5000 times in a short period of time is DDOS to the server on your own. None of IIS setting can help you on such scenarios. Find a way to prepare the jobs in advance and in a single call to your database. Then put the jobs in a cache somewhere, so that when those calls arrive at web server you can quickly respond from the cache. Then you need less timeout and queue length.

Comment: thanks @LexLi. I could potentially use a cache or something similar to avoid the database lock but even after that, individual nodes periodically post status updates to the web server and those are recorded in the database. This does not require a lock on the database but there still could potentially be 5,000 API calls within a very short period of time. Is there a standard approach to managing this scenario? 5,000 requests doesn't seem like too much for IIS and presumably SQL server can handle that many connections, I just want to make sure that my configuration settings don't create issues

Comment: With a cache in between and proper data sync up (cache/database), you can minimize the API call each to just a few ms. Then IIS and your web framework will be happy to serve thousands of them. I just commented that your original design has flaws (each call can take seconds and more, and pending on database lock). IIS/database can of course take as many requests/connections as possible even with default settings, but it is the bad locking you described that breaks up concurrency.